# ¿Cómo poner activo un botón en especifico?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hice un código simple de `JS` que al darle click a una categoria muestra unos resultados.
Quiero que al iniciar la página, esté un botón activo mostrando los resultados correspondientes a ese botón y ocultando los otros resultados de otros botones.

Éste es el código:

```html
$("#mostrarmkt").on( "click", function() {
   $('#marketingprecios').show("slow"); //muestro por id el precio
   $('#diseñogprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
   $('#diseñowprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
   $('#asesorprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
   });
  $("#mostrardiseñog").on( "click", function() {
   $('#diseñogprecios').show("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
   $('#marketingprecios').hide("slow"); //muestro por id el precio
   $('#diseñowprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
   $('#asesorprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
   });
```

Gracias!

Comment: Podrías poner esto al final de tu código para ejecutar el click de uno de los botones así: `$("#mostrarmkt").click();`

Answer (score 1):

Todo en el mismo JS

```
        $("#mostrarmkt").on( "click", function() {
            $('#marketingprecios').show("slow"); //muestro por id el precio
            $('#diseñogprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
            $('#diseñowprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
            $('#asesorprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
         });
        $("#mostrardiseñog").on( "click", function() {
            $('#diseñogprecios').show("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
            $('#marketingprecios').hide("slow"); //muestro por id el precio
            $('#diseñowprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
            $('#asesorprecios').hide("slow"); //mientras muestro el de arriba, oculto este
         });

        $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#mostrarmkt").click()
        });
```